# vim delete regex: pattern not found

Tags: regex, vim

This is my first time trying to use a regex for deletion.
The regex:

`/net=.+\.net/`

[as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/bK3oP3/1) matches a string that starts with `net=` some random characters and ends with `.net`
However, when using it in vim:

`:g/net=.+\.net/d`

I simply get `Pattern not found: net=.+\.net`

I am guessing that vim uses a slightly different format, or do I need to escape the characters `=`, `.` and `+` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help pattern` is your friend. In your case, you need to escape `+` or prefix your whole pattern with `\v` to turn it “verymagic”.

Do not escape `=`, it would turn it into the same thing as `{0,1}` in some regexp engine, namely a greedy optional atom matcher.